# how to compute this definite integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

how to compute $\displaystyle I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\tan x}\,dx$

i made $f(x)=\frac{x}{\tan x}$ and then i see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\tan x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x}{\sin x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\\
&=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\cos x}{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1\\
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x}{\tan x}=0
\end{align}$$

we have that $f(x)$ is decreasing into $(0,\pi/2)$ and $f(x)\in(0,1)$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, then i think that

$$0<\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{xdx}{\tan x}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

i think the primitive can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions, then i think that other method like residue theorem or power series would be used, but i dont know how to use any of these, how i compute this integral?

Comment: There is no elementary antiderivative, so taylor series would be your best bet.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2} \log 2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration by parts gives

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\tan x}dx=\left. x\log (\sin x)\right|_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2$$

Comment: I knew that there had to be some simple and elegant way that I missed. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Thanks.  Your solutions are always very creative!

Answer (score 5):

Define $I(b)$ as: 
$I(b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{\tan^{-1}(b\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}dx}$ 
It is not hard to show that $f(x,b) = \frac{\tan^{-1}(b\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ are both continuous in $x$ and $b$. Then 
$
\begin{align*}
I'(b) &= \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{\tan^{-1}(b\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}dx} \\
      &= \int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\tan^{-1}(b\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}dx} \\
      &= \int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{dx}{(b\tan(x))^2+1}} \\
      &= \frac{\pi}{2(b+1)}
\end{align*}
$

Integrating with respect to $b$ leads to: $I(b) = \frac{\pi}{2}\log(b+1)$ 
So the original integral is:
$\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{xdx}{tan(x)}} = \frac{\pi}{2}\log(2) $

Ref. "INTEGRATION: THE FEYNMAN WAY" from one of the MIT open course web sites

Comment: How did you evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+b^2\tan^2 x}dx$ so readily?  While the integrand has a closed form anti-derivative, it requires a bit of work (e.g., Weirstrauss substitution).   Just curious.

Comment: @Dr. MV: should be easy to evaluate using $\int{\frac{dx}{a+b\tan^2(x)}}=\frac{1}{a-b}\left[ x - \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} \tan(x) \right) \right]
$

Comment: Yes, it isn't difficult.  But, it takes a bit of effort ... that is all I meant.  I like the "Feynman" trick by the way.  Here, there is a more direct way forward.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Letting $x=\tan t$ and integrating by parts with regard to $~\dfrac{\arctan t}{t^2+1}~dt=d\bigg(\dfrac{\arctan^2t}2\bigg)$, then doing the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of $\dfrac{\arctan t}t$ with itself after expanding $\arctan t$ into its Taylor series and dividing each term by *t*, we switch the order of summation and integration only to obtain an infinite series which is immediately recognized as the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the [Mercator series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for $\ln2$ and the [Leibniz series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi) for $\dfrac\pi4$.

Comment: I would think that this is obvious.