# Evaluate $ \int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}dx $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

Can I evaluate this integral:

$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}dx
$$

without knowing the value of $\zeta(2)$? In particular can I use methods of complex analysis?

Comment: Such integral *is* $\zeta(2)$, by the substitution $x=e^{-t}$ and the integral representation of the $\zeta$ function, for instance. What are you exactly looking for? A direct proof of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which does not exploit the identity $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, for instance?

Comment: In such a case, you may have a look at the Pace-Ritelli approach outlined [in this classical thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617710/44121).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403819/how-to-integrate-int-01-frac-ln-xx-1dx-without-power-series-expansion/3404200#3404200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x-1}\,dx&=\Big[\ln(1-x)\ln x\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx\end{align}$

and read my answer,
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2632547/186817

Answer (score 3):

$$-\int^{1}_{0}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx=-\int^{1}_{0}\ln x\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^ndx$$

$$=-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\int^{1}_{0}x^n\ln(x)dx$$

By parts method

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)$$

Comment: Still, you need to prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ separately, which is what I believe the OP wants to avoid.